# Having trouble stepping through function that reduces an array of functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce, higher-order-functions

When using the reduce method on an array of functions I am having difficulty tracing through how reduce works on the array exactly.

```
comboFunc(num, functionsArr) {
  return functionsArr.reduce(function (last, current) {
    return current(last);
  }, input);
}
```

so with `functionsArr = [add, multi]` and the functions `add` and `multi` being

```
function add(num) {
  return num + 1;
}
```

and

```
function multi(num) {
  return num * 30;
}
```

the function `comboFunc` would:

```
comboFunc(2, functionsArr); //returns 90;
```

I understand how the reduce method works on an array of numbers folding the array into one value as it were, by applying a function to each element of the array. This example with comboFunc taking an array of functions as a parameter uses simple enough math that I can understand how reduce produces the value of 90 mathematically but I don't understand what is happening line by line and on each iteration from a functional level. I'm unable to articulate in my mind what exactly is happening when---how the input of 2 is getting passed from function to function vis-a-vis closure and the sequential firing off of each function, etc.

If the reduce method applies the function you pass in to each element of an array, and when each element in the array is a function...how can I write out for my own understanding syntactically how that looks?

The function passed into the reduce method returns `current(last)` so that's a function returning a function. So that would make `last` equal to the `add` function and `current` equal to `multi`? In other words returning `multi(add)`? If my logic is correct, this means what is happening is that the input then gets passed into `add` and computed and then that returned value is passed into `multi` and computed to ultimately return 90?

Comment: No, `last` is the last *value*, not a function. `current` is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) function that takes an array of functions to apply to an input, *num*

Let's first cover a couple syntax errors. First you're missing the `function` keyword

```
// your code
comboFunc(num, functionsArr) {

// should be
function comboFunc(num, functionsArr) {
```

Next, you've named your parameter `num` but then you reference it as `input` in the function body

```
// your code
}, input);

// should be
}, num);
```

So after you fix this, your function works, but what if we approach the problem a little differently?

> **Disclaimer:** this answer does not walk you through the function you've provided. Rather, it sympathizes with your difficulty by demonstrating `comboFunc` was written in an overly complex way. In turn, I give you an alternate definition of your function that operates identically but is a *lot* easier to read/understand.

To begin, I think we should go back to the basics of function composition.

I like picturing function composition as a little map.

```
  f(x)=y      g(y)=z
+--------> y -------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   v
x ----------------> z
          ?
```

In the example above, we could easily replace *f* with your `add` function, and *g* with your `multi` function. Defining *?* should also be fairly obvious now.

```
  add(2)      multi(3)
+--------> 3 -------+
|                   |
|                   |
|                   v
2 ----------------> 90
  h(x) = g(f(x))  = z
  h(x) = (g∘f)(x) = z
  h(2)            = 90
```

*(g∘f)* can be said "*g* of *f*" and it just means apply *x* to *f* first, then apply that result to *g*.

Notice *y* isn't even present. We've defined *h* in terms of an *x* that gives us a direct "map" to a *z*, skipping over *y* entirely.

Composing two functions together is a very basic operation, and we could define a function to do that very easily

```
function comp(g,f) {
  return function(x) {
    return g(f(x));
  }
}

var h = comp(multi,add);

   h(2);                   // 90
// h(2) = multi(add(2))    =  90
```

***"Yeah, but I'm trying to work with N functions. Not just 2."***

OK, `comp` works for two functions, but I've over simplified the problem. You're probably wondering how this would work if we wanted to compose 3, 4, or even more functions together.

Well let's look at it again

```
a(w)              = x
b(x)              = y
c(y)              = z
d(w) = c(b(a(w))) = z
d(w) = (c∘b∘a)(w) = z
```

Look very closely at the `∘`. We know this to be our `comp` function and we can see it appear between each of our functions, *a*, *b*, *c*.

Before we go further, let's say we have an array of numbers

```
var xs = [1,2,3];
```

If we want to sum the numbers, we would need to call

```
var sum = 1 + 2 + 3
```

See how the `+` appears between each number? With our array of functions, it's no different!

```
var fs = [c,b,a];
var d  = (c ∘ b ∘ a)
```

We just need to make that valid JavaScript. And it'll be easy too because we've already defined `∘` as `comp`.

This calling of a function between terms in a list is called a linear [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) and JavaScript has a function that does this called `reduce`.

Alright, so let's put it use! We'll fold ("reduce") our list of functions using our `comp` function

```
function compN(fs) {
  return fs.reduce(comp);
}

var h = compN([multi, add]);

   h(2);                   // 90
// h(2) = multi(add(2))    =  90
// h(2) = (multi ∘ add)(2) =  90
```

OK, so it works for our original two functions, but let's make sure it works with an even longer list

```
var i = compN([multi, add, add, add]);

   i(2);                               // 150
// i(2) = multi(add(add(add(2)))       =  150
// i(2) = (multi ∘ add ∘ add ∘ add)(2) =  150
```

> Ok, so let's recap

```
function add(num) {
  return num + 1;
}

function multi(num) {
  return num * 30;
}

function comp(g,f) {
  return function(x) {
    return g(f(x));
  }
}

function compN(fs) {
  return fs.reduce(comp);
}

compN([multi, add])(2); // 90
```

***"But why is this better?"***

Just as we cut out `y` in `h(x) = (g∘f)(x) = z`, notice how our `compN` function doesn't concern itself with `num`, `last`, or `current`. We've dropped 3 variables for our brain to think and it's much clearer what our function is doing.

`comp` takes *f* and *g* and composes them together to make `g ∘ f`.

`compN` calls `comp` between each term in a list of functions

To me, this is very straight forward and easy to understand. Just looking at the function bodies for each `comp` and `compN`, I can identify the intent immediately.

> Compare that to

```
comboFunc(num, functionsArr) {
  return functionsArr.reduce(function (last, current) {
    return current(last);
  }, input);
}
```

It's no wonder you had difficulty trying to follow it. `comboFunc` was concerning itself with too much from the very onset because it's trying to be two operations instead of just one.

So, I know I didn't step you through your original function, but I hope after reading this answer you have an even greater understanding of function composition and building your own functions with separated concerns.

---

**EDIT**

According to some discussion below, it would be valuable for our `compN` function to work on an empty array, `[]`.

```
var f = compN([]);
// Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

**Yuck!** The intended behavior here will be for `compN` to create a function that returns an unmodified input.

```
function id(x) {
  return x;
}
```

Using this as the starting point for the reduce will guarantee that our `compN` function will work even when an empty array is given

```
// revised compN
function compN(fs) {
  return fs.reduce(comp, id);
}
```

Check it out

```
compN([])(2);           // 2
compN([multi, add])(2); // 90
```

Now `compN` will work for an array of 0 or more functions.

Comment: Notice that function composition as a fold should start with the identify function, just as "sum" expressed via fold would start with 0.

Comment: @Bergi that's not necessary. If you call `reduce` without a second argument, the first item in the list will be used as the initial item and iteration will start with the second item. Using the code above, `compN` will even work with an array of a single function: `compN([function(x){return x+2;}])(2);` returns `4`.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work with an *empty* array - that's the whole point. Never write non-total functions if you can avoid them. Same thing for sum: `sum([])` should yield `0`, not throw an error.

Comment: @Bergi, I appreciate your review <3 I agree it is best to make functions total when possible. I made an update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've called it (with two arguments), `Array#reduce` calls your callback once for each entry in the array.

On the first call, the `last` argument is the value you gave at the end (`input`, in your case) and the `current` argument is the first entry in the array. Your callback is calling that entry (your first function) passing in `last`, and so the first function is called with `2`. Since that's `add`, the result of calling it is `3`, which you then return from your callback.

On the second call, the `last` argument is what you returned on the previous call; so it's `3`. The `current` argument is the next function in the array. In your case, that's `multi`, and so you call it with `3`. `multi` returns `90`, which you return.

The result of the `reduce` is the last value the callback returned. So, `90`, in your example.

You can think of this form of `reduce` like this (this is **not** literally what it does, `reduce` is more complicated; this is a simplified version):

```
// Again, this is a *simplified* example
function pseudoReduce(array, callback, initialValue) {
    var index, last;

    last = initialValue;
    for (index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {
        last = callback(last, array[index], index, array);
    }
    return last;
}
```

(`Array#reduce` would behave *slightly* differently on the first pass if you didn't give it that second argument; that's not reflected above.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to understand what is happening is to add `console.log()` to your code so you can see what is happening step-by-step:

```
function comboFunc(num, functionsArr) {
  return functionsArr.reduce(function (last, current) {
    console.log(current + " " + last + " ==> " + current(last));
    return current(last);
  }, num);
}

function add(num) {
  return num + 1;
}

function multi(num) {
  return num * 30;
}

var functionsArr = [add, multi];
console.log( comboFunc(2, functionsArr) );
```

Output:

```
"function add(num) {
  return num + 1;
} 2 ==> 3"
"function multi(num) {
  return num * 30;
} 3 ==> 90"
90
```

This essentially is

```
multi(add(2)); // (2+1)*30 = 90
```